# Could not load my.sql.jdbc.Driver, while configuring Solr to import data from mysql Database

Tags: jdbc, solr, jetty, classpath, dataimporthandler

I have added "`mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar`" to solr/lib where other *jetty*.jar files are present. But when in solr/admin I check java.classpath I dont find this `mysql.connector jar`.. so finally on doing a full import i get the error

"`java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Could not load driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver Processing Document # 1`"

Comment: try to put it on the jettyHome/lib/ext directory.

Answer (score 4):

The jars are picked by Solr depending upon your configuration :-

- solrconfig.xml - the [lib](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml#lib) directives specified in the configuration file are the lib locations where Solr would look for the jars. So you would need to ensure the jar is present in one of the lib directories.
- [solr.xml](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin#solr) - In case of the Multi core setup, you can have a sharedLib for all the collections. You can add the jdbc driver into the sharedLib folder.

[Oracle_Example](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Oracle_Example)

Comment: yes, it worked after i added the directory withing "<lib>" tags in solrconfig.xml. For me it was not working when the jar was in jettyHome/lib/ext, i had to explicitly mention.

Comment: cool ... if its solves your problem .. you can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

For Solr 4.5.1, 
Add mysql connector to lib folder.
Add lib folder path to solrconfig.xml

```
<lib dir="../../lib" />
<lib dir="../../../contrib/extraction/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
<lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-cell-\d.*\.jar" />

<lib dir="../../../contrib/clustering/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />
<lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-clustering-\d.*\.jar" />

<lib dir="../../../contrib/langid/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />
<lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-langid-\d.*\.jar" />

<lib dir="../../../contrib/velocity/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
<lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-velocity-\d.*\.jar" />

<lib dir="../../../contrib/dataimporthandler/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
<lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-.*\.jar" />
```

that is worked for me.